# CanDeactivateFn in Ionic Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-router-guards

I would like to implement a CanDeactivate Guard in my Ionic Angular application. I've found out, that I should use the new "CanDeactivateFn" Guard, but I can't found any information or an example how to do it.
Can somebody give me an example? That would be very helpful!

Comment: Next time maybe lookup in the official docs https://angular.io/cli/generate#guard-command. Try this -> ng g guard name --functional. If using angular cli >= 16 the flag --functional will be the default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export const GlossaryOutGuard: CanDeactivateFn<GlossaryComponent> =
(
    component: GlossaryComponent,
    currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    currentState: RouterStateSnapshot,
    nextState: RouterStateSnapshot
): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree  =>
{
    let sweetAlertService: SweetAlertService = inject(SweetAlertService);

    if(component.viewMode == 'GLOSSARY' && component.isSomeMenuItemUnderEdition()) {
        let menuItemUnderEdition: EditGlossaryItemComponent = component.getMenuItemUnderEdition()!;
        return sweetAlertService
            .showGlossaryDataLosingQuestion(menuItemUnderEdition.label!)
            .then((result: SweetAlertResult) => result.isConfirmed);
    }
    return true;
}
```